# If ln(field) gives an error, just 0, else ln(field)

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying a natural log transformation on a field. For most values of the field this makes sense, but there are some values less than 0. In this case I'd like to either make null or replace with 0.

```
select ln(0)
Invalid floating point operation: log(e,0)
```

I found references to [try_cast()](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/try_cast.html), but this doesn't seem appropriate for my need.

Is there a way I can try `ln(field)` and not error if snowflake encounters a value =< 0?

Comment: If the values are only 0 and positive then `SELECT LN(NULLIFZERO(field)) FROM tab` could be used

Comment: @LukaszSzozda NULLIFZERO, that's a handy one, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the IFF function to do this.

```
set my_val = -1;

select iff($my_val <= 0, null, ln(abs($my_val)));

set my_val = 2;

select iff($my_val <= 0, null, ln(abs($my_val)));
```

Someone may notice the `ln` function has an `abs` around the value and spot a superfluous expression. This is for error safety. I've seen cases with some functions where both sides of a conditional or list of expressions will be evaluated. Even though one part will be thrown away by the IFF or COALESCE, etc, it's safer to make sure math expressions won't lead to an error even in what should be unreachable forks.

Comment:  for bullet-proofing and mentioning that short-circut of the case expression may not happen on 100% cases.

Answer (score 1):

you can use case if you want.

```
select  case
        when column1=0 then 0
        when column1< 0 then 0
        else column1
    end as result
from 
(   select * from values
   (1) , (92) , (-3), (0)
   );
```